# Google Cloud Storage via App Engine fails to generate_signed_url after upgrade, complaining about credentials

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have an App Engine program that was successfully using `generate_signed_url` in google-cloud-storage 1.24.1 when running Python 2.7, using this code:

```
from google.cloud import storage    
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket(estate.bucket_name) 
blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
url = blob.generate_signed_url(version="v4", expiration=datetime.timedelta(hours=5), method="GET")
```

Having "successfully" upgraded to Python 3.9 and google-cloud-storage 2.10, and deployed to the cloud, everything is going great until that call to `generate_signed_url`.  At that point I get:

> AttributeError: you need a private key to sign credentials.the credentials you are currently using <class 'google.auth.compute_engine.credentials.Credentials'> just contains a token. see https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html#setting-up-a-service-account for more details.

My understanding is that under these circumstances it's supposed to "just work"... and it did before the upgrades. In fact, the old version
is still published and still works.  From the page linked in the error message:

> If you’re running in a Google Virtual Machine Environment (Compute Engine, **App Engine**, Cloud Run, Cloud Functions), authentication should **“just work”**.

I'd prefer not to go down the rabbit hole of setting up and  authenticating service accounts (assuming that would even work).  Any ideas?

Comment: The service account private key is unavailable when running on a compute service. That means you must use one of the IAM sign functions (SignBlob, SignJwt) to have Google sign using their managed private key. There are a number of published solutions for Python 3. You did not show the code you use, which is always a good idea on Stack Overflow. Note: changing Python versions is not the problem. The library is the issue. Which library and version were you using and now using?

Comment: @John, really appreciate the help!  I have updated my question to include the code, and the google-cloud-storage library versions.  I don't understand your comment about the IAM sign functions, though, since this is running on App Engine (even though the message references Compute Engine), and used to work.

Comment: App Engine, Cloud Run, Cloud Functions, and Compute Engine all have one thing in common. They fetch access tokens from a metadata service. Those services do not have access to the service account private key. The error message is a bit misleading but the problem is the same for all compute services. You cannot directly sign data. You must use the Cloud IAM API to do signing.

Comment: This [article](https://medium.com/@evanpeterson17/how-to-generate-signed-urls-using-python-in-google-cloud-run-835ddad5366) has example code to generate Cloud Storage Signed URLs in Python 3 when running under a compute service such as App Engine.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I guess you are implicitly saying that things have changed behind the scenes when I move to App Engine Python 3/google-cloud-storage 2.10.  I will attempt to follow the instructions in the article and report back.

Comment: I have been careful to just state the reason for the problem because I don't know the details of this issue within the libraries. I am now going to review both libraries for generating Cloud Storage Signed URLs so that I know the exact issue when you upgraded from Python 2 to Python 3. In the meantime, you can use the code in the article that I referenced to solve the problem today.

Comment: Following the steps in the [article](https://medium.com/@evanpeterson17/how-to-generate-signed-urls-using-python-in-google-cloud-run-835ddad5366) works: thanks!!  Couple of minor items for posterity: unmentioned by the article, you need to enable the IAM Service Account Credentials API, and for App Engine, there's no need to create a separate service account: you can just add the Service Account Token Creator role to the default service account.  Presumably (untested), you could also set the service_account in app.yaml and use a separate service account as outlined in the article.

Comment: @JohnHanley, if you want to post your comment as an answer, I can mark this solved.